# Spring boot Activemq Transport Connection failed: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a Spring Boot Application 2.2.6.RELEASE.
I'm using spring-boot-starter-activemq (active-mq 5.15.12)

I'm trying to configure 2 brokers one primary and one secondary:

```
broker.url: "failover:(tcp://192.168.0.28:61616,tcp://localhost:61616)?randomize=false&priorityBackup=true"
```

But if the primary fails (I stop the activemq broker), I have an exception and it never switches to the secondary

```
WARN  - Transport (tcp://192.168.0.28:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: {} 
java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I start the app without the primary and then turn on the primary I also have an exception and no message are sent nor received (even if it says that it is succefully reconnected)

```
WARN  - Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:61179 failed: java.io.EOFException 
INFO  - Successfully reconnected to tcp://192.168.0.28:61616
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using an appender for my Log.

```
public class LogAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> implements CommandLineRunner
```

This appender publish the log to the broker

```
@Override
protected void append(ILoggingEvent event) {
    ServerLogLine log = new ServerLogLine(event);
    if (logPublisher != null) {
        logPublisher.publish(log);
    }
}
```

But with failover option when the broker stops, FailoverTransport class sends a LOG:

```
LOG.warn("Transport ({}) failed {} attempting to automatically reconnect: {}",
                     connectedTransportURI, (reconnectOk ? "," : ", not"), e);
```

And because of my LogAppender, the program blocks here.

Correction in init method of LogAppender:

```
// Remove log level for activemq
logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache.activemq");
logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel("OFF"));
```